# d3.js create the pie chart but square shaped

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, charts

Just started using d3.js and javascript. I have this weird chart requirement. Want to create the chart exactly like pie chart but, in square shaped. Just like below.

[image]

So, I thought, may be I create the pie chart and add the square between the pie chart and erase the part outside square. But, it is not working out yet.

Secondly, I thought, I can do this with CSS. I did this. But, I am not happy with this solution. It is too hacky. Can someone help me with good solution.

[This is my jsfiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitanya_sw/0fkozg22/5/)

```
//// Done this to create the square.
var svgContainer = d3.select("#square").append("svg")
                       .attr("width", 200)
                       .attr("height", 200);

var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .attr("y", 0)
                    .attr("width", 200)
                    .attr("fill", '#ec4c4a')
                    .attr("height", 200); 

// Done this to create the pie chart. Found this example some where.
var element_id = 'pie'
var elementSelector = '#pie';

        svgWidth = 390;
        svgHeight = 320;
        svgInnerRadius = 0;
        svgOuterRadius = 145;
        heightOffset = 0;
        scoreFontSize = '49px';

        $(elementSelector).replaceWith('<svg id="'+ element_id +'" class="scoreBar" width="'+ svgWidth +'" height="'+ (svgHeight - heightOffset) +'"></svg>');
        $(elementSelector).css({'width': svgWidth + 'px', 'height': (svgHeight-heightOffset) + 'px'});
        var anglePercentage = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
        var fullAnglePercentage = 100;
        var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#ACACAC", "#EAEAEA", "#123123", "#DDEEAA", "#BACBAC"]);

        data = [[50, 90, 1],
                [50, 30, 2],
                [30, 10, 3],
                [10, -1, 4],
                [-1, -10, 5]]

        var vis = d3.select(elementSelector);
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .innerRadius(svgInnerRadius)
                    .outerRadius(svgOuterRadius)
                    .startAngle(function(d){return anglePercentage(d[0]);})
                    .endAngle(function(d){return anglePercentage(d[1]);});


        vis.selectAll("path")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("path")
           .attr("d", arc)
           .style("fill", function(d){return color(d[2]);})
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + svgWidth / 2 + ", " + svgHeight / 2 + ")");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle appears to work just fine, even with the css removed. Not sure what more you expect. Is it about it stopping working when applying the dimensions from your question ?

Comment: You don't want to create a square-shaped pie chart. You want to go home, and rethink how to best visualize your data.

Comment: The thing about the pie chart is that the area coloured in is proportional to the values in the chart. With a square chart this is not the case, the corners will have a larger area than the midpoint of the sides.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using clip path. [What is a clip path?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath)

To SVG add defs of clippath

```
var svg1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//making a clip square as per your requirement.

svg1.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("id", "clip-rect")
        .attr("x", -120)
        .attr("y", -100)
        .attr("width", radius)
        .attr("height", radius);
```

Make your normal d3 pie chart like:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.data.age);
});
```

To the main group add the clip like this:

```
var svg = svg1.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/yu0h922L/2/).